# How to expire user token if particular field value is updated in User model in Django?

Tags: django, api, rest, signals

I'm trying to make a signal to expire the user token if a field value is updated in the User model.

This is the signal I've written. But for some reason, `instance.is_corporate_profile_admin` is giving older data and not the data which is recently saved or sent from the request when the API was hit.

**apps.py**

```
class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'user'
    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
        request_finished.connect(signals.task_token_expire)
```

**signals.py**

```
def expire_user_knox_token(user_id : int, time : object) -> bool:
    from knox.models import AuthToken
    try:
        _ = AuthToken.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).update(expiry=time)
        return True
    except:
        return False


@receiver(post_save, sender=UserDetail)
def task_token_expire(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance and instance.id:
        from django.db import transaction
        with transaction.atomic():
            from datetime import datetime
            logout_time = datetime.now()
            # If is_cp_admin value changed or if no user entry in UserDetailOlderValues then only token expire.
            try:
                older_is_cp_admin_value = UserDetailOlderValues.objects.filter(user=instance).order_by('-id').first().is_corporate_profile_admin
                print('older_is_cp_admin_value------------->', older_is_cp_admin_value)
                print('new value------------->', instance.is_corporate_profile_admin)    # ! THIS VALUE IS NOT THE LATEST VALUE WHICH IS SENT IN THE REQUEST
                if instance.is_corporate_profile_admin != older_is_cp_admin_value:
                    expire_user_knox_token(user_id=instance.id, time=logout_time)
                    _updated= UserDetailOlderValues.objects.filter(user=instance).update(is_corporate_profile_admin=instance.is_corporate_profile_admin, last_token_expired_at=logout_time)

            except:
                expire_user_knox_token(user_id=instance.id, time=logout_time)
                _obj, _created = UserDetailOlderValues.objects.update_or_create(user=instance, is_corporate_profile_admin=instance.is_corporate_profile_admin, last_token_expired_at=logout_time)
```

I tried using pre_save before post_save, to hold previous data but both pre_save and post_save are fetching same older data. So, I created another model to save older data of `is_corporate_profile_admin`. But in post_save `instance.is_corporate_profile_admin` still reflects older data.

Here is my `UserDetailOlderValues` model:

```
class UserDetailOlderValues(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='udov', blank=True, null=True)
    is_corporate_profile_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_token_expired_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_detail_older_values'
```

Along with that, I'm getting this as well: `TypeError: task_token_expire() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'`.

Comment: I think the problem is in your apps.py refer to this post https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: I tried using signals both ways with post_save. But for some reason it is triggering the method `task_token_expire` before saving value in database.